# Actionscript 4: NetConnection.connect(...) does not fire a NetStatusEvent event

Tags: events, actionscript, red5, netconnection

I downloaded the red5-recorder (http://www.red5-recorder.com/) , which fails to allow me to start recording. After debugging I found that the netconnection, needed to record to a media server, created does not fire a NetStatusEvent event, so essentially it fails silently. I have implemented the connection with the following minimal working example:

```js
trace("make net connection");
nc = new NetConnection();
nc.client = { onBWDone: function():void{ trace("bandwidth check done.") } };
trace("add event listener");
nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, function(event:NetStatusEvent) {
    trace("handle");
});
trace("connect!");
nc.connect("rtmp://localshost/oflaDemo/test/");
trace("connect done");
```

The output of this piece of code is:

```js
make net connection
add event listener
connect!
connect done
```

The actionscript api states that the connect-call always fires such an event:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetConnection.html#includeExamplesSummary

Moreover, the netconnection is not 'connected' (a state of the NetConnection object) 10 seconds after the call. I also took a look at this:  [NetConnect fails silently in Flash when called from SilverLight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808137/netconnect-fails-silently-in-flash-when-called-from-silverlight)  But the fix suggested by the author, swapping rtmp and http in the connection uri, do not work. Also, I tested the uri and in fact the exact same code sniplet in a personal project, where it did work. I just can not seem to find why connecting to a media server fails silently in the red5-recorder project.

The awkward part is that if I pass some random string as a conenction uri, still nothing happens (no event, no exception, no crash). Also not setting nc.client becore nc.connect(), which caused exceptions in my experience, did not cause exceptions.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: There is no such thing as Actionscript 4.

Comment: I'm sorry. I am using Flex 4.5 (With flash builder 4.5) with Actionscript 3. My mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the address to **localshost** instead **localhost**.

```
nc.connect("rtmp://localshost/oflaDemo/test/");
```

Correct address:

```
nc.connect("rtmp://localhost/oflaDemo/test/");
```

Comment: Yet, is it acceptable that no error-event is fired by the netconnection?

Comment: i just tested your code and the error-event fired after like 10 seconds